# Neoload with OMS Monitoring

Tags: azure, neoload

One of our customer has setup a OMS (Operations Management Suite) based monitoring setup to capture a metrics/logs during the performance test runs.
We are trying to understand on how to analyze the OMS based logs, if there are someone who have already experienced on analyzing the OMS based logs and created a report based on it. please share us your experience or any relevant document related to OMS based reporting

OMS - > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/operations-management-suite/operations-management-suite-overview

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Log Analytics for this. It can be accessed from either OMS portal or the Azure portal. You can leverage log searches where you construct queries to analyze collected data, dashboards, which you can customize with graphical views of your most valuable searches, and solutions, which provide additional functionality and analysis tools.

Refer: [View or analyze data collected with Log Analytics log search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-tutorial-viewdata)

Comment: Thanks for that Shihab. Let me try with it.